# Uploading failed due to this error

Tags: android, fragment

Where possible, set exported=false for the PreferenceActivity in your Manifest. This will prevent foreign apps from sending Intents to this class.

If the vulnerable PreferenceActivity must be exported to foreign apps then determine why the class is vulnerable and take the appropriate actions. There are two possibilities:

Incorrect implementation of isValidFragment:

Check if the vulnerable class contains or inherits an implementation of isValidFragment that returns true on all code paths. If this is true, then update the class to check for a list of allowable Fragment classes. For eg: If the PreferenceActivity should allow MyFragment classes and no other Fragments then implement a check like this:

```
     public boolean isValidFragment(String fragmentName) {
        return MyFragment.class.getName().equals(fragmentName);

     }
```

targetSdkVersion less than 19 and does not implement isValidFragment:

If the app currently sets its targetSdkVersion in the manifest to a value less than 19 and the vulnerable class does not contain any implementation of isValidFragment then, the vulnerability is inherited from the PreferenceActivity.

In order to fix, developers should either update the targetSdkVersion to 19 or higher. Alternatively, if the targetSdkVersion cannot be updated, then developers should implement isValidFragment as described in 1) to check for allowable fragment classes.